# nginx location block redirect regex is greedy

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I need to redirect pages below a dir but not the dir itself...

```
location ~* ^\/groups\/.+$ {
    return 301 /resource/;
}
```

The rule is matched when `/groups/` is hit but it should only match when something follows eg `/groups/XXX`

Any tips would be gratefully received

Comment: your code seems to be correct, the problem might be somewhere else, is this the only location for /groups url?, try adding , location = /groups {default_action};

Comment: @Satys yup! tried clearing browser cache - only other 'unusual' factor is this is running in a docker container and is mapped to port 8008 on the host - that shouldn't matter though